# pgadmin4 can't connect to postgresql 14

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I've installed postgresql 14 and pgadmin4 on Ubuntu 20.04.  I set a password with `sudo passwd postgres` and restarted postgresql  I've modified the METHOD settings in `/etc/postgresql/14/main/pg_hba.conf` to be `trust`.  But pgadmin4 refuses to connect with this message:[image]

This used to be all it took to get pgadmin4 to connect.

Is there something new in Postgresql 14 that has to be done?

Comment: have you reloaded the pg_hba? `pg_ctl reload`

Comment: also, is there anything in the log files that might give you a hint? Another possibility is that you restarted the wrong database, in case you have multiple instances running on the same machine.

Comment: The web page I was using had a missing step.  As the postgres user do  `psql -c "ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'secure_password_here';" `.  Setting a password for the postgres user in Linux isn't enough.  You've got to set it in the database as well.  I don't remember having to do this with older versions of postgresql.

Comment: I was about to check your method to set the password, as I always did it using `alter user` :D Nice you found the issue. Cheers

Comment: If you are using password authentication for connecting to the database you have always had to set a password for the  database user, `postgres` or any other. I suspect in the past you where using either `trust` or `ident\peer` authentication. `trust` requires no password  and `ident\peer` use the OS user.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, I was going crazy trying to resolve this issue for the last 3 days until I hit this post.

I recently installed PostgreSQL 14 on Ubuntu 20.04 and was trying pgAdmin 4 v. 6.7 and was not able to even create a server without having an INTERNAL SERVER ERROR message. The issue was that when installing PostgreSQL I simply used the same Linux root user password and did not specify a password for the postgres user as you mentioned in the line:

psql -c "ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'secure_password_here';"

Thank you